# Change certain paragraph text in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering if it was possible to change text dynamically in jQuery.

I want to display this in HTML --

```
A [dynamic animal name] is my favourite pet.
```

meaning that

```
[dynamic animal name]
```

should be inside an array of words, say

```
var wordArray = [cat, dog, cow]
```

How would i go about seperating the paragraphs into one that can be dynamically changed?

I was trying

```
<p>A <p id="special">[wordArray goes here]</p> is my favourite pet.</p>
```

but it turns out like this in html:

A cow

is my favourite pet.

meaning it breaks the whole line of words into 2 seperate sentences.

How do i make it go together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<p id="special">...</p>` use a `<span id=special"> ... </span>`

`span`is an inline element and will not break the view.

Another solution is to use css to make the `<p id="special">` element inline:

```
p#special{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: thank you for providing more than a single answer. that really helped!

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` tag will be the correct one instead of `<p>` tag for dynamic animal name

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`span`-tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span) for the *animal*:

HTML:

```
<p>A <span id="special">[wordArray goes here]</span> is my favourite pet.</p>
```

javascript:

```
$('#special').text(wordArray[2]);
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jz9vT/).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<p>A <span id="special"></span> is my favourite pet.</p>

var animals = ["cat", "dog", "cow"];

$("#special").text(animals[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<p>A <span id="special">[wordArray goes here]</span> is my favourite pet.</p>
```

You're using nested <p> tags that is why it's breaking into sentences/paragraphs.